# LeetCode 1263: Minimum Moves to Move a Box to Their Target Location ||

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting a follow-up code on this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247332/leetcode-1263-minimum-moves-to-move-a-box-to-their-target-location), which seems to be a version of [Sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban).

[image]

If you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

Storekeeper is a game in which the player pushes boxes around in a warehouse trying to get them to target locations.

The game is represented by a `grid` of size `m x n`, where each element is a wall, floor, or a box.

Your task is move the box 'B' to the target position 'T' under the following rules:

- Player is represented by character 'S' and can move up, down, left, right in the `grid` if it is a floor (empty cell).
- Floor is represented by character '.' that means free cell to walk.
- Wall is represented by character '#' that means obstacle  (impossible to walk there).
- There is only one box 'B' and one target cell 'T' in the `grid`.
- The box can be moved to an adjacent free cell by standing next to the box and then moving in the direction of the box. This is a push.
- The player cannot walk through the box.
- Return the minimum number of pushes to move the box to the target. If there is no way to reach the target, return -1.

#### Example 1:

[image]

<sup>Image Courtesy of LeetCode.com</sup>

```
Input: grid = [["#","#","#","#","#","#"],
               ["#","T","#","#","#","#"],
               ["#",".",".","B",".","#"],
               ["#",".","#","#",".","#"],
               ["#",".",".",".","S","#"],
               ["#","#","#","#","#","#"]]
Output: 3
Explanation: We return only the number of times the box is pushed.
```

#### Example 2:

```
Input: grid = [["#","#","#","#","#","#"],
               ["#","T","#","#","#","#"],
               ["#",".",".","B",".","#"],
               ["#","#","#","#",".","#"],
               ["#",".",".",".","S","#"],
               ["#","#","#","#","#","#"]]
Output: -1
```

#### Example 3:

```
Input: grid = [["#","#","#","#","#","#"],
               ["#","T",".",".","#","#"],
               ["#",".","#","B",".","#"],
               ["#",".",".",".",".","#"],
               ["#",".",".",".","S","#"],
               ["#","#","#","#","#","#"]]
Output: 5
Explanation:  push the box down, left, left, up and up.
```

#### Example 4:

```
Input: grid = [["#","#","#","#","#","#","#"],
               ["#","S","#",".","B","T","#"],
               ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#"]]
Output: -1
```

#### Constraints:

- `m == grid.length`
- `n == grid[i].length`
- `1 <= m <= 20`
- `1 <= n <= 20`
- `grid` contains only characters '.', '#',  'S' , 'T', or 'B'.
- There is only one character 'S', 'B' and 'T' in the `grid`.

#### Code

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_set>

class Solution {
    using size_type = std::int_fast16_t;
    static constexpr char kPLAYER = 'S';
    static constexpr char kBOX = 'B';
    static constexpr char kTARGET = 'T';
    static constexpr char kWALL = '#';
    static constexpr char kFLOOR = '.';
    static constexpr size_type kDIRECTIONS[4][2] = {{ -1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}};

public:
    int minPushBox(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& grid) {
        const size_type row_len = grid.size();
        const size_type col_len = grid[0].size();

        std::queue<std::pair<size_type, size_type>> player_box_q;


        std::unordered_set<std::pair<size_type, size_type>, player_box_hash> box_player_visited;

        size_type start = 0;
        size_type end = 0;
        size_type player_pos = 0;

        for (size_type row = 0; row < row_len; ++row) {
            for (size_type col = 0; col < col_len; ++col) {
                const size_type curr_pos = row * col_len + col;
                setCurrentPosition(grid, row, col, curr_pos, start, end, player_pos);
            }
        }

        if (start == end) {
            return 0;
        }

        player_box_q.push({start, player_pos});
        size_type pushes = 0;

        while (player_box_q.size()) {
            size_type qlen = player_box_q.size();

            while (qlen--) {
                const auto [box_pos, player_pos] = player_box_q.front();
                player_box_q.pop();

                if (box_pos == end) {
                    return pushes;
                }

                const size_type x_box = box_pos / col_len;
                const size_type y_box = box_pos % col_len;

                for (const auto& direction : kDIRECTIONS) {
                    const size_type next_x_box = x_box + direction[0];
                    const size_type next_y_box = y_box + direction[1];
                    const size_type next_x_player = x_box - direction[0];
                    const size_type next_y_player = y_box - direction[1];

                    if (!isValidPosition(next_x_box, next_y_box, row_len, col_len, grid) || !isValidPosition(next_x_player, next_y_player, row_len, col_len, grid)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    auto box_player_encode = std::make_pair(box_pos, next_x_player * col_len + next_y_player);


                    if (box_player_visited.count(box_player_encode)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (isAccessible(grid, player_pos, next_x_player * col_len + next_y_player, box_pos)) {
                        player_box_q.push({next_x_box * col_len + next_y_box, box_pos});
                        box_player_visited.insert(box_player_encode);
                    }
                }
            }

            ++pushes;
        }

        return -1;
    }

private:
    struct player_box_hash {
        std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<size_type, size_type>& key) const {
            return std::hash<size_type> {}(size_type(key.first) << 8 | key.second);
        }
    };

    static bool isValidPosition(
        const size_type x,
        const size_type y,
        const size_type& col_len,
        const size_type& row_len,
        const std::vector<std::vector<char>>& grid
    ) {
        return x >= 0 && x < col_len && y >= 0 && y < row_len && grid[x][y] != kWALL;
    }

    static void setCurrentPosition(
        std::vector<std::vector<char>>& grid,
        const size_type& row,
        const size_type& col,
        const size_type& curr_pos,
        size_type& start,
        size_type& end,
        size_type& player_pos
        

    ) {
        if (grid[row][col] == kPLAYER) {
            player_pos = curr_pos;
            grid[row][col] = kFLOOR;
        }

        if (grid[row][col] == kBOX) {
            start = curr_pos;
            grid[row][col] = kFLOOR;
        }

        if (grid[row][col] == kTARGET) {
            end = curr_pos;
            grid[row][col] = kFLOOR;
        }
    }

    static bool isAccessible(
        std::vector<std::vector<char>>& grid,
        const size_type start,
        const size_type end,
        const size_type box
    ) {
        const size_type row_len = grid.size();
        const size_type col_len = grid[0].size();
        std::queue<size_type> start_q;
        std::vector<bool> valids(row_len * col_len);
        start_q.push(start);
        valids[start] = true;
        grid[box / col_len][box % col_len] = kWALL;

        while (start_q.size()) {
            size_type qlen = start_q.size();

            while (qlen--) {
                const size_type curr = start_q.front();
                start_q.pop();

                if (curr == end) {
                    grid[box / col_len][box % col_len] = kFLOOR;
                    return true;
                }

                const size_type x_start = curr / col_len;
                const size_type y_start = curr % col_len;

                for (const auto& direction : kDIRECTIONS) {
                    const size_type x_next = x_start + direction[0];
                    const size_type y_next = y_start + direction[1];
                    const size_type curr_pos = x_next * col_len + y_next;

                    if (
                        x_next < 0 ||
                        x_next >= row_len ||
                        y_next < 0 ||
                        y_next >= col_len ||
                        grid[x_next][y_next] != kFLOOR ||
                        valids[curr_pos]) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    valids[curr_pos] = true;
                    start_q.push(curr_pos);
                }
            }
        }

        grid[box / col_len][box % col_len] = kFLOOR;
        return false;
    }
};
```

#### References

- [LeetCode 1263: Minimum Moves to Move a Box to Their Target Location](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/247332/leetcode-1263-minimum-moves-to-move-a-box-to-their-target-location)
- [Sokoban C++](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sokoban#C.2B.2B)
- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-moves-to-move-a-box-to-their-target-location/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-moves-to-move-a-box-to-their-target-location/discuss/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-moves-to-move-a-box-to-their-target-location/solution/)